# Relative generic flatness.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flatness

It is known that any morphism is flat at an open set of points. I'd like to know if there is a relative version of this fact.

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g:Y \rightarrow S$ be morphisms of varieties, and let $h=g \circ f$ be their composition. Suppose that $h$ and $g$ are flat. Is it true that the set 
$\{x\in X| f|_{h ^{-1}(h(x))} : h ^{-1}(h(x)) \to g ^{-1}(h(x)) \text{ is flat at } x  \}$
is open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With these assumptions, the set in question is the set of points in $X$ where $f$ is flat; hence it is open. This is "flatness by fibers", EGA IV (11.3.10) (applied with $\mathcal{F}=\mathcal{O}_X$).

Comment: I know that a map $f:X \to Y$ is flat in an open subset $U \subset X$. I just do not undestand why it implies what I need.

Do you claim that
$\\{x\in X| f|_{h ^{-1}(h(x))} : h ^{-1}(h(x)) \to g ^{-1}(h(x)) \text{ is flat at } x  \\} =$
$ = \\{ x \in X| f \text{ is flat at } x \\} $
?
Why?


Comment: I think I got it. EGA IV (11.3.10)  says that  $\\{x\in X| f|_{h ^{-1}(h(x))} : h ^{-1}(h(x)) \to g ^{-1}(h(x)) \text{ is flat at } x  \\} = \\{ x \in X| f \text{ is flat at } x \\}$. 

and EGA IV (11.3.1) says that the later is open.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Thank you very much.


Comment: That's right. The "open" bit is also stated at the end of (11.3.10).